# Force of exploding pumpkin

Tags: forces

Okay so in physics class we are going to explode a pumpkin by placing some kind of bomb inside of the pumpkin. Well us students have to come up with an apparatus to measure the force of the explosion, i am in desperate need of some help or some ideas of some solutions and what i need to measure to find the force of the explosion. I know that i need to find the mass of the chunks of pumpkin, the position of the pumpkin chunks from start to finish, and the time it took for the chunks to reach a certain point. What else do i need to know and/or find? PLEASE HELP

Comment: How many pieces will there be? If there aren't too many, can't you just use a camcorder and videotape the pieces flying, use the frame-by-frame playback to compute their velocities, then add them to get the total kinetic energy after the shearing of the pumpkin?

Comment: well, we are going to use a gopro, but my teacher wants us to know everything we would need to know to find out with out using it. what i was thinking was to weigh the biggest chunk of pumpkin and find out the acceleration of that chunk using the gopro then i was going to use the f=ma formula, but for some reason that just seems to easy so im not sure if it is right.

Comment: Perhaps you can confine the pumpkin in a container rigged with peessure measuring devices or push sensors, both of them will tell you the force that the masses are exerting at given distance and rest is all maths.

Comment: well you see, my teacher wants us to, for the most part use math and only math, other than the gopro. Also the spending limit that she gave us was 100 dollars that includes the amount of money shes going to spend constructing the explosion device. pretty much to sum it up all I really need to find out at the moment is the exact formulas and solutions I will need to calculate everything.

Answer (score 1):

At best you can make a confinement decorated with pressure measuring sensors. The pressure observed can then be used to find out witb what force the particles of explosive are hitting the sensors. The calculated acceleration ( found with force ) can be related to velocity of particles just before making impact. This can be traced backwards to with what velocity the particles started with. And everything related can be pretty much calculated with the obtained results.